# Can i use more than one reactjs version in one website?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing plugin using Reactjs. This plugin is easy to pluggable with any site. For plugin build, I am using "webpack" and follow commonjs/es6 module system. Suppose end user may be used react in their website, Is it affect my plugin? (ex: like two jquery we are using in website then we use jquery.noconflict())?

Note: I didn't export react outside. Is React maintain any information in global?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Most 3rd party React components require that the application consuming them provide a compatible version of React.

This is why you see React as a peerDependency in the `package.json` of these libraries.

Comment: I just tried here [link](https://vimalceg.github.io/test/). It is working for two version(Plugin - 15.6.1, others site - 0.14.9). screen short [link](https://vimalceg.github.io/test/ss.png). When will become problem? Any simple example. Thanks.